# Write $M=(e^{a_{i,j}})$ as a function of $A=(a_{i,j})$

Tags: matrices

I know that this matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{a_{1,1}} & e^{a_{1,2}} & e^{a_{1,3}}\\
e^{a_{2,1}} & e^{a_{2,2}} & e^{a_{2,3}} \\
e^{a_{3,1}} & e^{a_{3,2}} & e^{a_{3,3}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
can't be expressed as $\exp(A)$ where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\end{pmatrix}$$
In fact, as stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), the exponential of $X$ is the $n\times n$ matrix given by the power series
$$e^{X}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{1 \over k!}X^{k}$$
where $X^{0}$ is defined to be the identity matrix $I$ with the same dimensions as $X$.

Anyway, I would like to know if there is a way to write $M$ as a function of $A$.

Comment: Does $M \colon M_{n \times n} \to M_{n \times n}$, $A \mapsto [e^{A_{ij}}]$ answer your question?

Comment: @Y.Tamer thank you but no, it does not answer my question